# Assing received,formatted UDP char Array to unsigned integer in C

Tags: c, formatting, char, udp

I receive a char Array via UDP and run some format operations on it. Works fine.(it has the form dd:123)

I use the "dd" for my if cases. Now I need to save the 123 (saved in d)in an unsigned integer pwmValue0.

If anybody knows how to do this I would be very happy if you could help me out a little

Have a nice day!

```
recv(serverSocket, msg, sizeof(msg), 0);

        printf("Here is the message: %s\n", msg);

        char *c;
        char *d;
        c = strtok(msg, ":");
        printf("token %s \n", c);   //correct
        d = strtok(NULL,".");
        printf("token1 %s \n",d);   //correct

        if (strcmp(v0, msg) == 0) {
                printf("Motortest\n");
                printf("token2 %s \n",d); //correct
                pwmValue0 = d;  // How can I make this assignment?
```

Comment: If `d` is a NUL-terminated string representation of your number just do `pwmValue = atoi(d);`

Comment: `pwmValue0 = (unsigned int)strtoul(d, NULL, 10);` --> where `10` = base 10

Comment: Is the pwm value limited to 0-255? If so you should be sending a single byte, not a cstring.

Comment: yes its limited but there is some information before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtok` returns `char*` and you said your `pwmValue0` is an `unsigned int`, so you can use `atoi()`

**EXAMPLE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    char* p = "123";
    int d;
    d = atoi(p);
    printf("%d",d);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
pwmValue0 = strtol(d, NULL, 10);
```